# How to access the traffic volume (e.g. visits, pageviews) of a news page?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, yahoo-finance

I am evaluating whether I can analyze the popularity of a certain piece of news.

For example, if I want to know how popular this news is:

http://finance.yahoo.com/blogs/the-exchange/already-watch-comes-honey-boo-boo-now-smell-205512706.html

Am I allowed to query the server about the number of visits? in any server language.

I know there are some websites serving to do this like alexa. However, it cannot analyze a subpage like the one above. It will only return the result of yahoo.com in this example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more about your requirement. Because this can be easily done using Google analytics.

You can measure the basic info as you request and also user engagement , loyalty and frequently which is important for a content web site